# The entity type is not part of the model for the current context (Multiple Models)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created a new model:

```
public class MultipleModel
{
    public Imputation Imput2 { get; set; }

    public ImputationDetail ImputD2 { get; set; }

    public Projet Prjt { get; set; }
}
```

}
So I can use multiple tables in one View. But when I try to edit an entry I get "The entity type is not part of the model for the current context".
I added MultipleModel in my context :

```
public SDIconnexion()
        : base("name=SDIconnexion")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<MultipleModel> MultipleModels { get; set; }
```

And I get the error in the modelState.IsValid

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = D_Lun,D_Lun_Com")] MultipleModel imputationDetail)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(imputationDetail).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.ImputationId = new SelectList(db.Imputations, "ImputationId", "Semaine", imputationDetail.ImputD2.ImputationId);
        ViewBag.TacheId = new SelectList(db.TacheInPhases, "TacheInPhaseId", "Libelle", imputationDetail.ImputD2.TacheId);
        return View(imputationDetail);
    }
```

Comment: You have to add every entity, also Imputation, ImputationDetail and Project. For this properties also add virtual if you want lazy load.

Comment: I have already added them in my context. I just didn't show the whole code.

Comment: Are you using DB First? In this case the problem could be different

Comment: Yes I am using it.

Comment: Where the exception has thrown? This error often originated from model table class which still unregistered in EDMX context.

Comment: If you feel that the table(s) have been correctly added to the model through EF mapping, check the debug exception stack for any errors that are being thrown from the database. Table issues can also bubble up this exception.